# How to access Chrome's volume slider using CSS?

Tags: html5-video

[image]

What is the label/name of this HTML5 video control (inside the red outline)? 
I'm assuming it's for the volume slider?

It appears when I roll over a blank area (that previously had the volume's Mute icon) next to the Full-Screen button. If I click it, it does nothing.

**Problem**:
I need to hide its visibility. I have used CSS to hide and customise other `<video>` controls, just unsure what this one is called.

Comment: **Please FIX... There's not enough useful info to answer you correctly**... What browser's player UI are you asking about? Did you try any research like **checking** what is shown there before you add your own grey block as customization? Most likely it is **volume** but that's just a maybe regarding my own browser (_ie:_ Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc will have different UI designs so it depends on what you use)...

Comment: Sorry, its only showing in chrome.

Comment: If it's happening with Chrome then it will also be same in Edge browser. Notice how Firefox doesn't have a "hide on/off" effect on the volume slider so that one is easier to access. Anyways see if my Answer helps you. PS: I see you got down-voted for _"Lack of clarity"_ so I tested your code, and yes **it's not clear**, how those 3 lines of code create the problem in your picture. The edit is better though for understanding (so the downvote might get cancelled after a while).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:**

It is called `-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-hover-background`.

For future readers who want other specific options, try accessing `<video>` tag icons in your CSS as...

Volume icon (for mute/unmute):

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button { display: none; }
```

Volume slider (with range for loudness):

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider { display: none; }
```

Volume slider's *hover* background (the dark bar in your shown picture)

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-hover-background { display: none; }
```

**PS**: Or just hide the **container** of all these Volume icons...

Volume control container (for mute button, slider and slider background):

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-container { display: none; }
```

The above examples should solve the problem, but read further below for extra details.

**Full Answer:**

> *"What HTML5 video control is this? I need to hide it. 
>  I have hidden and customised other controls, just unsure what this one is.
>  I'm assuming it's for the volume slider (?). 
>   It is only happening in Chrome browser."*.

Not sure how your code is setup but maybe something below is useful to solving your problem:

**(option 1)** Try to find out the labels/names from the **Chrome source-code**.

Search for `volume` in the text at: [mediaControls.css](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/core/css/mediaControls.css?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F).

Strangely though, they do not list `-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-hover-background`, the one simple thing that you needed. Still you'll learn something, such as... **There is also** a `video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-slider` which you might need to also handle when user goes to fullscreen mode.

PS: I say *"might need"* because I don't know how much you've already handled, but I see a fullscreen icon (in your shown picture) so be prepared for a possible "Round 2" of this issue when that FS button is pressed.

**(option 2)** Analyzing a `<video>` tag's **volume** icon (in Chrome's Developer Tools) we can see...

- Moving the mouse "over" or "out" of the volume icon changes the `class=`.
- `class="closed"` means only the volume icon is showing (for mute/unmute).
- `class=""` means the volume slider/range part is also now showing.

```
<input  type="range" step="any" max="1" 
        aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-label="volume" 
        pseudo="-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider" 
        aria-valuenow="100" 
        class="closed" style="">

<input type="button" pseudo="-webkit-media-controls-mute-button" aria-label="unmute" style="" class="muted">
```

You can see there are three **pseudo** names. One of these names is the one you want to hide that (unwanted) dark bar.

- Either you want to make then `hidden`
- Or you want to change their `class=` setting.

Test the options and ask anything if still stuck.

Comment: Adding `video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-control-hover-background { display: none; }` to my CSS worked! Thank You.